# how to unzip a zip file when there is space in batch file

Tags: unzip

I have a scenario where I am checking whether there are any zip files in specific folder. If there is zip file then extract it to the same folder with `winzip.exe`.

For example I have a zip file (`Haritest.zip`) in `C:\Users\hari\Desktop\Hari Krishna` folder

I am doing in this way

1. winzip path in `....\WINZIP64.exe`
2. InFolder as `Desktop\Hari Krishna`
3. Filename as `Haritest.zip`

When I try to use the below command to unzip

```
%winzip% %InFolder%/%Filename%
```

it just opens winzip folder and does nothing. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If path contain spaces then use "" ..For Example "C:\Users\hari\Desktop\Hari Krishna\haritest.zip" .Enclose with double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the path that contains spaces in quotes:

```
%winzip% "%InFolder%/%Filename%"
```

Answer (score 0):

If path contain spaces then use "" ..For Example "C:\Users\hari\Desktop\Hari Krishna\haritest.zip" .Enclose with double quotes –

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a few questions about unzipping from a batch file, and surprisingly enough you don't require any unzipping software. just run this command, replace "Folder_where_ZIP_file_is with the folder that has the zip file in it e.g. the downloads folder. replace file_name.zip with the file name e.g. myzip.zip. and replace where to Where_to_unzip with the folder path for where you want to unzip.

```
CD Folder_where_ZIP_file_is
powershell Expand-Archive file_name.zip Where_to_unzip
```

this may not answer your question if the file NEEDS to be unzipped with WINZIP, but it is a lot simpler. if you know how to find an item path then you don't need the line with CD, you can just replace file_name.zip with it.